# What does Joker “with TM” mean in the Deck of Many Things?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, playing-cards

I was reading the entry for the Deck of Many Things in the Dungeon Masters Guide and I can't figure out what the difference is between the two joker entries. One says with TM and the other without TM.

How can I differentiate?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### TM means trademark.

Because jokers are a historically recent addition to playing card decks, they [do not have an established appearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joker_(playing_card)#Appearance).

In most decks of cards, the two joker cards are not identical. Generally speaking, the two jokers will fit into one of the following four cases:

1. One joker will be "standard", while the other will have a trademark of the deck's manufacturer (the "TM" joker)
2. Both jokers will have the manufacturer's name/logo, but one will also have some sort of printed guarantee for the deck (the "TM" joker)
3. The jokers will have identical art, but in different colors; usually one will be black while the other is red, but occasionally one will be colored in a variety of colors while the other is black & white
4. Both jokers will be identical

If your jokers are just different colors, the DM should specify which is the "TM" joker before players draw. If the jokers are identical then you should use a different deck.

SevenSidedDie recommends marking one of them if they're identical, but if you've ever played CCGs then you may find that thought as distressing as I do; they're just playing cards, though, they have no sale value! You're not ruining them. Finding a writing implement that can mark the coating most playing cards have might be more hassle than just grabbing another deck, though.

---

Example jokers from some decks I had on-hand:

[image: 2 sets of jokers]

The top 2 are an example of red/black, while the lower pair are an example of trademarked jokers with a guarantee.

Comment: I've been playing cards for about 40 years and can't recall ever seeing a deck of cards with identical jokers.

Answer (score 11):

Many decks of playing cards include 2 jokers, which are often differentiated slightly. One such differentiation is the presence or absence of a trademarked image, another is the presence or absence of a company guarantee, but the most common difference is that one joker is coloured and one is black-and-white.

The Deck of Many Things is just saying to use one joker to represent the Fool card and one joker to represent the Jester card.

Answer (score 9):

#### They're [distinct cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joker_(playing_card)#Appearance) in a standard (real-life) deck of playing cards.

In a (real-life) deck of playing cards the two jokers are distinct. Often one is in color, the other black-and-white. In other decks one Joker will bear a trademark <sup>(TM)</sup> notification while the other doesn't.

The table on DMG p.162 assumes that the (real-life) deck being used to generate draws from the *deck of many things* has a trademarked Joker. Thus *that* joker will be the Fool, the other will be the Joker.